# How to hide button until all fields are populated in react with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I've got a form in react, how do I hide the submit button until all fields have a value?
Form field:

```
        <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="textField">
          <Form.Control onChange={handleTextValueInput} value={textValue} />
        </Form.Group>
```

Button:

```
          <ButtonToolbar> 
            <Button onClick={doSomething}  variant="secondary" size="sm">
              Submit field
            </Button>
          </ButtonToolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if thats what you want, but here is a solution:

```
<ButtonToolbar> 
  {textValue.length > 0 &&
    <Button onClick={doSomething} variant="secondary" size="sm"> Submit field 
    </Button>
  }
</ButtonToolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) your button using the `&&` operator, based on `textValue`. Do read up on the official react documentation to learn how conditional rendering works.

Doing `textValue && <>...</>` will render it if textValue is not falsy, i.e it is not null, or an empty string.

```
<ButtonToolbar> 
  {textValue &&
    <Button onClick={doSomething} variant="secondary" size="sm"> Submit field 
    </Button>
  }
</ButtonToolbar>
```

If you need to check more than 1 field, you will need to chain the `&&` operator.

Comment: If `textValue == 0` then button is not show. The question only `have a value`, You have a bug when `textValue == 0`. You should use `??` instead of

Comment: @RyanNghiem You've a point there :) But `textValue` is of type `string`, not `number`. Hence, it will never be `0`, which is a number.  While `0` is falsy, `'0'` is truthy.